# change all select box value with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have some  selectbox html like this

```
<select class="orderselect" name="files_Article_json[]"> 
    <option value="1" selected="">general</option> 
    <option value="2">one</option> 
</select>
.
.
.
<select class="orderselect" name="files_Article_json[]"> 
    <option value="1">general</option> 
    <option value="2" selected="">one</option> 
</select>
```

in these selectbox, I can select multi `value="1"`  but I can only select one `value="2"`

I do it with this jquery code:

```
$(document).on("change", ".orderselect",function() {
    if($(this).val() == '2') { 
        $(".orderselect").val('1').prop('selected', true); // first set all select box value to 1
        $(this).val('2').prop('selected', true); // set current selectbox to 2
    }
});
```

NOW I want do it for three value.

```
<select class="orderselect" name="files_Article_json[]"> 
    <option value="1" selected="">general</option> 
    <option value="2">one</option>
    <option value="3">two</option>  
</select>
```

again,I can select multi `value=1`

I can select only one `value=2` (for every other select with `value=2`,value become 1).

I can select only one `value=3` (for every other select `value=3`,value become 1).

I try do it:

```
if($(this).val() == '2') { 

    // for all orderselect with 2 value:
    $(".orderselect").val('1').prop('selected', true);

    $(this).val('2').prop('selected', true);
}

if($(this).val() == '3') { 

   // for all orderselect with 3 value:
   $(".orderselect").val('1').prop('selected', true);

   $(this).val('3').prop('selected', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this little function out.  Worked real well for me:

```
<script>
$(document).on("change", ".orderselect",function() {
if($(this).val() != '1') { 
    var num = $(this).val();
    $.each($(".orderselect").not(this),function(){
        if($(this).val() == num){
             $(this).val('1').prop('selected', true);
        }
    });
}
});
</script>
```